# Python ProcessPoolExecutor issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to process PDF files in a folder using tesseract. Seems that the function works fine when executed on files synchronously, but when i try and implement processpoolexecutor, nothing happens. Would truly appreciate some help/insight.

System details:

- Ubuntu 22.04, i5, python 3.10.6 (venv), vscode

Code:

```
# scrap text from pdf's and store content in files for nlp analysis
# tried to use both camelot and tabular and both packages could not scrap the required table contents
# this script implements ocr using tesseract  

from glob import glob 
import pytesseract
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from pdf2image import convert_from_path as pdf2img
import pathlib as pl
import multiprocessing as mpc

def ProcessPDF(par_FilePath):
    lstImages = pdf2img(par_FilePath)
    intImgs = len(lstImages)
    strOCRd = ''
    for it, im in enumerate(lstImages):
        npg = '='*50+f'Pg:{it+1}'+'='*50+'\n' #end each page
        pgText = pytesseract.image_to_string(im) #perform ocr
        strOCRd += pgText + '\n' + npg # add to string
        print(f'Processing: {pl.Path(par_FilePath).name} : {int(it/intImgs*100)}%')
    fStem  = pl.Path(par_FilePath).stem
    fDir =  str(pl.Path(par_FilePath).parent)+'/'

    with open(fDir + fStem + '.txt', 'w') as fobj: #save file
        fobj.write(strOCRd)
    return f'Completed: {pl.Path(par_FilePath).name}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    strFolderPDF = r'/home/*****/proj/rfp_model/pdfFiles/'
    lstFiles = glob(strFolderPDF+'*.pdf')
    numFiles = len(lstFiles)
    numCPUs = mpc.cpu_count()
    print(f'Starting pool executor, processing {numFiles} files with {numCPUs} workers.')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=numCPUs) as ppe:
        ftrResults = ppe.map(ProcessPDF, lstFiles)
    
        for ftrResult in as_completed(ftrResults):
            print(ftrResult)

    #this works 
    #for ipath in lstFiles:
    #    ProcessPDF(ipath)
```

Current Outcome:

- When run in the debugger i can see each of the threads spin up in the call stack, but then nothing. No activity the console. The system monitor shows each of my 4 cpu's hit 100%. I experimented by setting 1, and 2 workers, but no success. Waited for 10 minutes before hitting interrupt.
  Expected Outcome:
- Should see 4 processes kick off and print statements in the console as the function works through each page of each pdf.

Comment: pytesseract.image_to_string may raise an exception. You should manage that possibility

Comment: thanks, the function works good when executed outside of the process pool executor, but i can see that it can potentially generate. i'll add that in, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You've given me much to consider and look up @K J. I considered spinning up a small aws cluster, but that might be overkill, when some good old fashion patience will do just fine. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

ProcessPoolExecutor's map function does **not** return *future* objects

Change:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=numCPUs) as ppe:
        ftrResults = ppe.map(ProcessPDF, lstFiles)
        for ftrResult in as_completed(ftrResults):
            print(ftrResult)
```

...to...

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=numCPUs) as ppe:
        ftrResults = ppe.map(ProcessPDF, lstFiles)
        for ftrResult in ftrResults:
            print(ftrResult)
```

Your current code will induce an AttributeError exception

Comment: Thanks DarkKnight, you're right, submit returns a future, while map doesn't. I made the change and executed with no change in the outcome.

Comment: @rrrrrrs Did you wrap image_to_string in try/except?

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight, yes i have since yo posted earlier, with the same results unfortunately. Thanks for your help.